# cell labels are not refreshing in table

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am attempting to call a reloadData on my table's rows on a viewDidAppear method access.  However, my cells are not refreshing their values and I cannot figure out why, as it seems everything is being accessed in the order it is suppose to.  To make matters more odd, 1 row actually does refresh, but none of the others do.

Here is my code...

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{     
  // Set up the cell...
  static NSString *CellWithIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellWithIdentifier];
  NSLog(@"generating cell contents");
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellWithIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text = [_tableGroup.options objectAtIndex:rowcount];
    rowcount++;

    //label for currently selected/saved setting
    _currentSetting = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 8, 115, 25)];
    [_currentSetting setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    _currentSetting.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _currentSetting.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    _currentSetting.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;


    [cell.contentView addSubview:_currentSetting];
    NSLog(@"added new label to cell");
}

//depending on the setting, set the label in the cell to what is currently selected
if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {
    _currentSetting.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[settings.mapDistance stringValue], NSLocalizedString(@"MILES_IDENTIFIER", nil)];
    NSLog(@"setting map distance label: %@", settings.mapDistance);
}
else if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1)
{
    _currentSetting.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[settings.maxCustomers stringValue], NSLocalizedString(@"ITEMS_IDENTIFIER", nil)];
    NSLog(@"setting max customers: %@", settings.maxCustomers);
}
else if(indexPath.section == 2)
{
    _currentSetting.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[settings.maxProducts stringValue], NSLocalizedString(@"ITEMS_IDENTIFIER", nil)];
    NSLog(@"setting max products: %@", settings.maxProducts);
}

return cell;
}
```

based on this code, i get this output with my NSLOGS.

this is the first run of the cells when the view is created.  It generates 4 cells, puts labels in each cell, and in 3 of those labels, puts in a value.

```
 generating cell contents
 added new label to cell
 generating cell contents
 added new label to cell
 setting map distance: 15
 generating cell contents
 added new label to cell
 setting max customers: 250
 generating cell contents
 added new label to cell
 setting max products: 150
```

at this point i have clicked a row, went to a different screen, and have now returned.  as you can see, map distance is different.  although no change is displayed, even though the code to change the label's text is accessed during the reload process.

```
 reloading data
 generating cell contents
 generating cell contents
 setting map distance: 25
 generating cell contents
 setting max customers: 250
 generating cell contents
 setting max products: 150
```

again, I'm at a loss because the last row DOES refresh correctly.  But none of the others do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reload your tableView, the cells already exist and are dequeued from the tableView, so the condition `if (cell == nil)` returns false, and the cell creation code is not executed.

In that cell creation code, you are assigning a value to `_currentSetting` and then proceed with the acode assuming that value is correct. However, when the cell creation code is not executed, that value points to the latest created cell, and thus, it won't update.

To fix this: make _currentSetting a local variable and change the code to look like this:

(You don't really need to make it a local variable, but it's more appropriate because you don't really need a reference to the last label you created after you leave this method)

```
UILabel *_currentSetting = nil;
if (cell == nil) {
    _currentSetting = ...
    _currentSetting.tag = 123;
}
else
    _currentSetting = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:123];

...
```

Comment: I see what you are saying.  But what is the correct syntax to get the correct cell label?  your  `_currentSetting = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:123];` line gives a warning about incompatible types.

Comment: @JesseDurham _currentSetting = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:123]; will do the job

Answer (score 0):

The second time around, you can see that "`added new label to cell`" isn't being called, so you're re-using an old tableViewCell.

Note that you're not setting `_currentSetting` when re-using a cell, only when creating a new cell. So `_currentSetting` is set to the last new cell that was created, most likely the last cell in the table.

You need to make sure to set `_currentSetting` to the correct label (maybe by using `viewWithTag:`  or something similar).

(e:f;b)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the second time (when you are reloading the view ) the _currentSetting is not having a valid memory .So it is better to implement a custom cell and do the job

Better refer this [an excellent guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1)